# How create batch process in requests elixir phoenix

Tags: python-requests, process, elixir, phoenix-framework

I must create an api with great performance and I want to create it with Elixir
I have a process (slow) that I must run after some requests. I want to make this flow

In each request, save the data received in memory
After x requests, send to another api (or after x seconds)

In node I can make this:

```
let batchData = []
const handlerRequest = (req, res) => {
  batchData.push(req. body.data)
  if (batchData > 1000) {
    // Process to send to another api
    batchData = []
  }
  res.json({ success: true })
}
```

Or

```
let batchData = []
setInterval(() => {
  if (batchData > 1000) {
    // Process to send to another api
    batchData = []
  }
}, 10000)

const handlerRequest = (req, res) => {
  batchData.push(req. body.data)
  res.json({ success: true })
}
```

How can I do something like this in Elixir Phoenix?

Thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using a GenServer. I presume you want to start the timer when the first item is received.

```
defmodule RequestHandler do
  use GenServer

  @name __MODULE__
  @timeout 5_000
  @size 5

  def start_link(args \\ []) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, args, name: @name)
  end

  def request(req) do
    GenServer.cast(@name, {:request, req})
  end

  def init(_) do
    {:ok, %{timer_ref: nil, requests: []}}
  end

  def handle_cast({:request, req}, state) do
    {:noreply, state |> update_in([:requests], & [req | &1]) |> handle_request()}
  end

  def handle_info(:timeout, state) do
    # sent to another API
    send_api(state.requests)
    {:noreply, reset_requests(state)}
  end

  defp handle_request(%{requests: requests} = state) when length(requests) == 1 do
    start_timer(state)
  end

  defp handle_request(%{requests: requests} = state) when length(requests) > @size do
    # sent to another API
    send_api(requests)
    reset_requests(state)
  end

  defp handle_request(state) do
    state
  end

  defp reset_requests(state) do
    state
    |> Map.put(:requests, [])
    |> cancel_timer()
  end

  defp start_timer(state) do
    timer_ref = Process.send_after(self(), :timeout, @timeout)
    state
    |> cancel_timer()
    |> Map.put(:timer_ref, timer_ref)
  end

  defp cancel_timer(%{timer_ref: nil} = state) do
    state
  end

  defp cancel_timer(%{timer_ref: timer_ref} = state) do
    Process.cancel_timer(timer_ref)
    Map.put(state, :timer_ref, nil)
  end

  defp send_api(requests) do
    IO.puts "sending #{length requests} requests"
  end
end
```

And here is a few tests

```
iex(5)> RequestHandler.start_link
{:ok, #PID<0.119.0>}
iex(6)> for i <- 1..6, do: Request
[Request, Request, Request, Request, Request, Request]
iex(7)> for i <- 1..6, do: RequestHandler.request(i)
sending 6 requests
[:ok, :ok, :ok, :ok, :ok, :ok]
iex(8)> for i <- 1..7, do: RequestHandler.request(i)
sending 6 requests
[:ok, :ok, :ok, :ok, :ok, :ok, :ok]
sending 1 requests
iex(9)> for i <- 1..3, do: RequestHandler.request(i)
[:ok, :ok, :ok]
sending 3 requests
iex(10)>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GenServer](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html) or [Agent](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Agent.html)

### GenServer

The general idea is to have a GenServer process that holds the data to be processed and also handles the background processing. Using `GenServer.cast/2` we can send a message to a process asynchronously. So whenever, the controller receives the request, we'll add a new item to the queue and also check if batch size is reached and process it.

```
# In Controller (page_controller.ex) module
def index(conn, params) do
   App.BatchProcessor.add_item(params)
   conn|>json(%{success: true})
end
```

Add module for GenServer. You can add a new file `lib/batch_processor.ex`

```
defmodule App.BatchProcessor do
   use GenServer
   
   @batch_size 10 #whenever queue reaches this size we'll start processing
   
   def init(_) do
     initial_queue = []
     {:ok, initial_queue}
   end
   
   def start_link()do
      GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [], [name: __MODULE__])
   end
   
   #api function to add item to the 
   def add_item(data)do
      GenServer.cast({:add, data}, __MODULE__)
   end

   # implement GenServer behavior function to handle cast messages for adding item to the queue
   def handle_cast({:add, data}, queue) do
       update_queue = [data | queue] #addpend new item to front of queue
       
       #check if batch size is reached and process current batch
       if Enum.count(updated_queue) >= @batch_size do
          #send async message to current process to process batch
          GenServer.cast(__MODULE__, :process_batch)
       end
       {:noreply, updated_queue}
   end

   #implement GenServer behavior function to handle cast messages for processing batch
   def handle_cast(:process_queue, queue)do
     spawn(fn ->
        Enum.each(queue, fn data -> 
           IO.inspect(data)
        end)
     end)
     {:noreply, []} # reset queue to empty
   end
end
```

Start the BatchProcessor process when the Phoenix app starts

```
#application.ex

children = [
  # Start the endpoint when the application starts
  supervisor(App.Web.Endpoint, []),
  # Start your own worker by calling: App.Web.Worker.start_link(arg1, arg2, arg3)
  worker(App.BatchProcessor, []),
]
```

Read more on [GenServer](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html)
Hope this helps